How can you create particle hair / hair curves that resemble stylized hair strands?
Sorry for this kind of question but I really am struggling a lot.
What would you say would be the best way to make this hair as particle hair?
The main problem comes from the fact that most of the hair strands have a considerable width but really small depth so I have no clue how to properly work with it.

I'm trying for it to be this type of hair, but on the shape of the hair below.



In the two images above I try to show what I mean when I say they have some width but really low depth.



Do you have to use the hair particles or could you use the (new) hair curves? (requires at least Blender 3.3 IIRC). Hair curves can be converted into hair particles (for example for the use of Hair Dynamics) but this would still require Blender 3.3. Just asking because if you already have a stylized hair cut you can convert the strands to hair guides with Geometry Nodes. Wait, are the strands merged at the head?

I apologise but I don't quite understand what merged at the head means, it is very likely they are, I don't know if you mean if they converge at the center and are merged altogether, in that case, yes, sorry again. About wether do I have to use the hair particles or could you use the (new) hair curves, I guess that any way that gets a result would be fine, I just want to make it look like somewhat real hair but on that shape, and want to know what the best way to approach it would be since this has driven me crazy for a while (because of my lack of experience). Sorry for trash english.

You can use a mesh (like stylized hair curves or hair cards) to style the hair curves. In Blender you can convert the (old) Hair Particle System to the (new) Hair Curves, and vice versa.
In this example we use the new Hair Curves so we can use Geometry Nodes to create the hair guides.
For older Blender versions, you can use the Hair Net add-on to use a similar workflow. Have a look here Is there a way to make a hair particle look like a mesh I've already made?
First, you need a mesh that defines the hair style. Ideally, the strands should be separated and have straight UV islands. You can use a Bezier curve (1) to guide the hair strand and a deformed Circle curve (2) as a profile as well as another Bezier curve for the taper (3). Lower the resolution (4) a bit.

If you convert this curve to a mesh (menu Object > Convert > Mesh) you get a mesh that has a grid-like UV map. This allows you to delete the "horizontal" mesh loops and only keep the edges that are to serve as hair guides.

This Geometry Nodes modifier deletes the edge loops with help of the UV map. If you have hair cards or a mesh in which the UV islands are aligned vertically (from top to bottom), you must swap the X and Y values for the Equal and Substract math nodes.

To apply the Geometry Nodes modifier and convert the curve/mesh into a Curves object choose menu item Object > Convert > Curves.
Now you have a hair Curves object that you can attach to a surface object. Here is a checklist to make sure it works properly:

the Curves object is a child of the surface object (Suzanne)
the settings in the Curves properties tab for the Surface and UV Map are correct
it has a Surface Deform Geometry Nodes modifier
the surface object (Suzanne) has the Add Rest Position checkbox enabled. It's below the shape keys.
select the Curves object, switch to Sculpt mode and run the menu item Curves > Snap to Nearest Surfaces to re-attach the curves.
change Curves > Shape to Strip and increase Additional Subdivision in the render settings

Now you can groom hair in Sculpt mode, e.g. add more hairs with the Interpolation settings.

Or use modifiers from the Asset Browser, for example Duplicate Hair Curves to thicken the hair and Clump Hair Curves to create some strands.

